# Charles proxy with Appium

Tags: appium, charles-proxy

Can anyone give steps to invoke Charles proxy with Appium. I have a scenario where I need to capture and modify the request and response from Mobile App. For that I need to invoke Charles proxy with my selenium code. Can anyone help here?

Comment: did you figurate what to do, I also need for my native app. Thanks

Comment: Not yet, still waiting for help.